# Find probability that $x^2+y^2 \leq N^2$ where x and y are random positive integers less than N

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find $\lim_{N \to \infty} P(x^2+y^2 \leq N^2) $ where $x$ and $y$ are random positive integers less than N.

I want to calculate it using the law of total probability:

$\lim_{N \to \infty} P(x^2+y^2 \leq N^2) =  \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N\frac1N P(y^2 \leq N^2-i^2) =\lim_{N \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^N  \frac{\sqrt{N^2-i^2}}{N^2}$.

Here I am stuck, because I do not understand how to calculate this sum.

Comment: HINT: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/montecarlopi/MonteCarloPiMod/Images/MonteCarloPiMod_gr_11.gif This image hints you that the probability is $\pi /4$

Comment: I understand the picture and intuitively understand that it is pi/4, but I am stuck in expressing this fact formally

Comment: You should write $x_N$ and $y_N$ to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2+y^2 \le N^2$ is the part of a disc with radius $N$ in the first quadrant.
The area is $\frac 14 \pi N^2$

$0 \le x,y \le N$ is a square with area N^2.

So the probability is $\dfrac{\frac 14 \pi N^2}{N^2} = \dfrac \pi 4$

In fact $\lim_{N \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^N  \frac{\sqrt{N^2-i^2}}{N^2}$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \ dx$

Answer (score 3):

Just write it as a Riemann sum and compute the following integral:

> > $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\left(1-x^2\right)}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: It is encouraged that you explain in your answer and not leave it up to the OP unless they have asked for some hints. $(+1)$ for your first answer nonetheless :)